# C# MongoDB How to Deserialize to ImmutableList<T>

Tags: c#, mongodb, deserialization, immutability

I just stumbled over this - I registered my `Record`s which include some `ImmutableList`s.

Basically, like this:

```
record A {
   [BsonId]
   string Id {get; init;}
   string Name {get; init;}
   ImmutableList<string> Properties {get; init;}
};

record B {
   [BsonId]
   string Id {get; init;}
   string Name {get; init;}
   ImmutableList<A> Members {get; init;}
}
```

Now, serializing those to my MongoDB works fine, everything looks like it should. However, the deserialization back in to the `Record`s does not work, from the exception thrown it seems that the `Add` method does not quite work the way the deserializer expects (well, sure, instead of adding to the list itself it instead returns a new list with the added item).

Now, I found how to write a basic deserializer myself - but the nested `A` in `B` makes it a bit painful and it's quite brittle (e.g. if I later add additional nullable fields). What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please provide details.

Answer (score 0):

This [improvement](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-3432) raised with MongoDB explains the behavior and a possible solution by creating a custom serializer just for `ImmutableList<T>`:

```
public class ImmutableListSerializer<TValue> : 
 EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializerBase<ImmutableList<TValue>, TValue> 
{
  protected override object CreateAccumulator() =>
    ImmutableList.CreateBuilder<TValue>();
  protected override ImmutableList<TValue> FinalizeResult(object accumulator) =>
    ((ImmutableList<TValue>.Builder)accumulator).ToImmutable();
 
}
```

You can register this serializer for the required properties either on the properties themselves:

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(ImmutableListSerializer<string>))]
public ImmutableList<string> Properties { get; init; }

// ...

[BsonSerializer(typeof(ImmutableListSerializer<A>))]
public ImmutableList<A> Members { get; init; }
```

Alternatively, you can register it globally when initializing the application:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(
    typeof(ImmutableList<A>), 
    new ImmutableListSerializer<A>());
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(
    typeof(ImmutableList<string>),
    new ImmutableListSerializer<string>());
```

The downside is that you need to do this for each list type you need, but there is hope that the driver will support this sooner or later.

Comment: It's already supported: `BsonSerializer.RegisterGenericSerializerDefinition(typeof(ImmutableList<>), typeof(ImmutableListSerializer<>));`